# Returning a wide range of results (string values) from a function

Tags: c#

I'm writing a class library for licensing which is going to be referenced by an application. Now i need to return a wide range of responses like error connecting to the server, temporary license detected, demo going on, demo expired, licensed version, license expired, license renewed etc. What is the best method to return these responses other than sending it as a plain string value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestions:

1.You can return an object that has a message and a type.

2.You can have a base class and inherit different classes from it that are different type of responses.

for example:
`public abstract class LicenseType

{

public abstract string Message{get;}

}

public class DemoLicensed:LicenseType

{

public override string Message

{

return "Demo Licensed";

}

}
`

3.if something goes wrong with your licensing service I suggest you throw an exception instead of returning a response.

Comment: Of course i throw an exception when something goes 'wrong'. But do i really need to create 20 classes if i've 20 different responses?

Comment: No, you create diffrent instances of the same type to return.

I would only use exceptions when an actual error occurs, a revoked license is one of the expected possible outcomes, so don't use an exception for that.

Comment: So you can go with suggestion number 1 and have a Typed class.
Although I think the second suggestion is more compatible with Open-Closed principle.

Answer (score 2):

Return an object.  If the object has a ToString() method that generates reasonable string representation of the object contents, then you get the ease of working with a string return when you want it, and a lot more data when you need it.

This is basically what Exception objects are.